# Connection to Ubuntu Apache2 server times out

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, ubuntu-12.04, webserver

I am running ubuntu 12.04, with apache2.
My router configuration is set to forward port 80 to my local IP.
The problem is I can only access the server as localhost. Else it times out (from devices using the same network).
I do not have sfw firewall enabled, neither shorefirewall. Nothing.
It is very strange, what else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I cannot access from the same network, it must be from outside.

To fix it we could use hairpin NAT.